# Connection to external api from Azure

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-apps

please is there a way to connect to an external api from azure portal,
and if possible how can i create a flow that calls the api ,
get data and loads into an azure sql server table

Thanks.

Comment: If your query is to access API, then you might use the self-hosted gateway feature expands API Management support for hybrid and multi-cloud environments and enables organizations to efficiently and securely manage APIs hosted on-premises and across clouds from a single API Management service in Azure. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview For how to use it, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Azure portal is the dashboard to maintain all your azure resources so you cannot connect to an external API from azure portal.

Either you need to have your custom application code that will call any of your external API and insert the data to azure SQL server using any of the supported languages and host in any of the azure services like azure function, webapps etc.

In case if you don't want to write any code then you can leverage the logic app to create the workflow with any of the supported triggers (timer trigger, HTTP trigger etc.)

To call the external API you can leverage the [Native HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http). Once you get the response from your external API you can leverage the [SQL connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) to insert the data.

**Workflow:**
[Timmer Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence) --> [Native HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) --> [SQL connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/)